# How to design aggregate roots for stock tracking model using DDD?

Tags: many-to-many, domain-driven-design, aggregateroot

For the following anemic domain model:

- `stock: id, code, description, total_amount` - specific stock type, and `total_amount` is calculated to speedup views showing remaining quantity,
- `stock_arrival: id, date, document_id` - stock arrival event, and references document with details using `document_id` for bureaucracy/history reasons,
- `stock_arrival_line: stock_arrival_id, stock_id, quantity, unit_price` - line describing specific stock change on arrival, including pricing,
- `stock_removal: id,...` - stock removal event,
- `stock_removal_line: stock_removal_id, stock_id` - line describing specific stock change on removal event,
- ... other change stock events ...

The anemic domain model has following relation constraints:

- `stock_arrival_line:stock_id` references `stock:id`,
- `stock_arrival_line:stock_arrival_id` references `stock:id`,
- `stock_removal_line:stock_id` references `stock:id`,
- `stock_removal_line:stock_removal_id` references `stock:id`,

---

Probably, `stock` and `stock_arrival`/`stock_removal` should be aggregate roots,..

Domain above shows, that there's many-to-many relationship between `stock` and `stock_arrival`/`stock_removal` via mapping tables, and that's the main part which concerns me.

The invariants should be defined only on aggregate root and it's internals. Therefore, within `stock` aggregate, there's need to store `stock_arrival_line`/`stock_removal_line`, in order to make `stock` aggregate complete.

However, the same applies to aggregate roots `stock_arrival`/`stock_removal`, that they need to contain within themselves `stock_arrival_line`/`stock_removal_line` respectively, in order to make these aggregate roots about events complete.

When following DDD, where should these `...line`(s) belong? Should they be duplicated? Or, should it be modeled completely differently?

---

Disclaimer for possible close-voters: I had finished computer science studies, and there was heavy split between data and operations. Recently, I've stumbled across domain driven design, and started learning it, and it's quite different approach, and I'm lost about this many-to-many relationship and aggregate roots.

Comment: This is not an answer, but maybe it would help you to review what [GS1 has done](https://www.gs1.org/standards/edi-xml/xml-inventory-report/3-2). GS1 is a global standardisation organisation who have agreed a model for common business processes based on the knowledge of industry experts. So you may find that the work has been done for you, or at least find it useful to see how someone else thought stock control should be modelled.

Comment: @TomW, thank you! Seems to be an interesting standard. First, I thought, I wanted to model "stock tracking", not inventory, but,.. I found https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/inventory-vs-stock/, and inventory is exactly what I wanted.

Comment: interesting, I didn't fully appreciate that distinction either. It's slightly strange in the context of GS1 as for the most part those standards are focused on the processes of doing business, in which case stock as per the article you linked to would seem more meaningful than inventory.

Answer (score 0):

The `Stock` should be the aggregate root in your case. `StockArrival` and `StockRemoval` can extend the event class and you can rename it to `StockArrived` and `StockRemoved` with respect to the past tense specific of the event type object. Also, the events can contains a list of `Line` instances (where `Line` is an abstract class which is subclassed by `StockArrivalLine` and `StockRemovalLine` ) and reference the `Stock` aggregate through the `stockId` attribute from the event class. In real life, a `Line` on a document doesn't have an `id`, but an `orderNumber`. In case of `id` attribute from the `Line` class, the name sounds very synthetic, I think that you should rename it to `orderNumber`.

Comment: Thank for the answer, however it misses `total_amount` property of `Stock`. How should it be kept in consistent state? I was doing some research in mean time, and I think, that it's perfect case for read models. Ie. `StockStatus` or `StockAvailability`, which has this property computed from stock events. And, that read model can be easily cached. Can you please cover that part in answer?